# Remove all mentions of string from JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

In my web application, a user has the choice to enable and disable certain "notification preferences", their choices are added to an array for each possible category and alerts within a JSON object, this is then saved to the database, I'm trying to remove ALL mentions of a specific "channel" if it's set without having to know what to loop over and what nested items I have.

For instance, the following structure:

```php
$channels = json_encode([
    'domains' => [
      'expiry' => ['mail', 'database', 'slack']
    ],
    'ssl' => [
      'expiry' => ['mail', 'database', 'slack']
    ],
    'monitors' => [
      'up' => ['mail', 'database', 'slack'],
      'down' => ['mail', 'database', 'slack']
    ]
]);
              

$preferences = json_decode($channels);
```

I'd like to somehow find all mentions of **slack"" and then simply remove that item from my arrays, it may not always be in the same position, depending on what a user enables/disables...

I was thinking of using `unset` or something similar?

How can I achieve this with my code?

Comment: Loop through it and do your checks. Writing to a new object will be preferable to updating the object you are looping through.

Comment: Because I can't find the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php and the question is already closed, here's the code you need.

        $categories = get_object_vars($preferences);

        foreach($categories as $categoryName => $settings) {

     $settingsNames = get_object_vars($settings);
     
          foreach($settingsNames as $settingsName => $values) {
          $preferences->$categoryName->$settingsName = array_filter($values, function($item) {
           return $item !== "slack";
          });
         }
        }